# Which style of code is better: being efficient or separating concerns?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I wonder if this might come down to personal taste or if there is a generally agreed upon answer to this. I've got a piece of code that could be written in one of two ways and though I think it's something of a trivial example in terms of efficiency, I'd like to know what the generally accepted answer is for future extrapolations.

Here's the code I currently have, essentially a score is passed and some text is updated accordingly. The colour of the text is also changed by the score value.

```
function getBSTotalText(score) {
        var scoreText;

        if (score >= 0 && score <= 12) {
            scoreText = "0 - 12 HIGH RISK";
        }
        else if (score >= 13 && score <= 14) {
            scoreText = "13 - 14 MODERATE RISK";
        }
        else if (score >= 15 && score <= 16) {
            scoreText = "15 - 16 LOW RISK";
        }
        else if (score >= 16) {
            scoreText = "16+ NO RISK";
        }
        else {
            scoreText = "";
        }

        return scoreText;
    }

    function getBSTotalColour(score) {
        var colour;

        if (score >= 0 && score <= 12) {
            colour = "red";
        }
        else if (score >= 13 && score <= 14) {
            colour = "amber";
        }
        else if (score >= 15 && score <= 16) {
            colour = "yellow";
        }
        else if (score >= 16) {
            colour = "grey";
        }
        else {
            colour = "white";
        }

        return colour;
    }
```

Now I could easily refactor this into one function and just get it to return an array or object to save basically copying and pasting the same code into a distinct function which from my understanding would conform to DRY but then break SOLID. Would best practice be to keep these functions distinct or merge them into one?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'd say there's a compelling reason to refactor to a single function as both functions are concerned with the same thing - getting some formatted text.

```
function getBSTotalDisplayInfo(score) {
    var result = {};
    if (score >= 0 && score <= 12) {
        result.colour = "red";
        result.scoreText = "0 - 12 HIGH RISK";
    }
    else if (score >= 13 && score <= 14) {
        result.colour = "amber";
        result.scoreText = "13 - 14 MODERATE RISK";
    }
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 16) {
        result.colour = "yellow";
        result.scoreText = "15 - 16 LOW RISK";
    }
    else if (score >= 16) {
        result.colour = "grey";
        result.scoreText = "16+ NO RISK";
    }
    else {
        result.colour = "white";
        result.scoreText = "";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what part of the code is repeated and move that into an extra function. In your case it's actually quite easy:

```
function getBSTotal(score) {
    // returns some kind of enum
    if (score >= 0 && score <= 12)
        return 0;
    else if (score >= 13 && score <= 14)
        return 1;
    else if (score >= 15 && score <= 16)
        return 2;
    else if (score >= 16)
        return 4;
    else
        return 5;
}
function getBSTotalText(score) {
    // now map the enum either to a text
    return ["0 - 12 HIGH RISK",
            "13 - 14 MODERATE RISK",
            "15 - 16 LOW RISK",
            "16+ NO RISK"
           ][getBSTotal(score)] || "";
}

function getBSTotalColour(score) {
     // … or map it to a color
    return ["red",
            "amber"
            "yellow",
            "grey",
            "white"
           ][getBSTotal(score)];
}
```

You still can make it more efficient by evaluating `getBSTotal(score)` only once and passing that to the mapping functions instead of `score`.